# System.NullReferenceException in System.Core.dll at end of MainWindow() Constructor (C# WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a simple Window in C# with some elements in it. When i try to run it i get a "System.NullReferenceException in System.Core.dll". In debugging the Exception is raised at the end of the MainWindow-Constructor (where the brackets are)

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
        InitializeComponent();
        user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        handler = new DataHandlerPlants();
        tbTransponder.Focus();
        loadgrid(); //gets grid-Items from DB
        loadComboboxes(); //gets combobox-Items from DB
    } //Here is where the exception is raised
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Can you update the question with the code of the method?

Comment: @SebastianHofmann just did it

Comment: @AleksAndreev I already read the answers, but there is nothing that could fit here

Comment: There is not enough information, put here full exception stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Just realised the problem:

I added grouping to a GridView but the column by which should be grouped is not available.